# Can I save label title in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to save label title in laravel.

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
```

Suppose I want to save "Name" in database.

Comment: yes it is, through jquery + laravel. Get text from label through jquery and then post to store method.

Comment: actually, this needs more details. Where that label come from? Who created that label? Why do you need to save that label?

Comment: Ayaz shah, can you please help me with sample code.

Comment: Smankusors, the label is coming from database. I want to store label name so I can use it later. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <label for="name" name="'+ value +'">' + value + '</label>. This is how i am getting my label name using jquery.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. <input type="hidden"> works. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden field and make its value the same as the label name.

`<input name="label" value="Name" type="hidden">`

Or you can use something like

```
<form action="youraction" >
 <label for="male">Male</label>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[W3Schools - documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

It will also depend on your use-case may be more information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

according to your structure, the label name comes from db, so when you are rendering the blade, you can make a hidden input with value of label name like below:

```
<form action="{{ route('sampleRoute') }}" >
 <label for="{{ $DBVARIABLE }}">{{ $DBVARIABLE }}</label>
 <input type="text" name="{{ $DBVARIABLE }}" id="{{ $DBVARIABLE }}" value="{{ $DBVARIABLE }}" style="visibility: hidden;">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: why not `type="hidden"`??

Comment: Cause i forgotten hidden type at all 